# RxJS: How to return a cached response until the request parameter values are changed

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a request that needs to be checked each time: If the parameter value of the request is changed, the request should be executed, otherwise the request should be skipped and the response of the previous request should be returned instead.

```
private resultObs$: Observable<any> = new Subject<void>().asObservable();

return merge(
            this.http.get<model>(`${this.apiUrl}`),
            this.resultObs$
            ).pipe(
                shareReplay(1)
            )
```

Comment: You mention canceling if the parameter values change, but your code doesn't show any parameters.  Please further explain what you want to achieve and show more relevant code.

Comment: By "canceling" he meant "skipping the http-request" (and returning a cached response instead).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to achieve the following:

- Cache the response
- Return the cached response as long as the input-parameter don't change.

Your code could then look something like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  private cache$!: Observable<User>;
  private previousParameter: string = '';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getUser(userId: string) {
    if (!this.cache$ || userId !== this.previousParameter) {
      this.cache$ = this.requestUser(userId).pipe(
        shareReplay(1)
      );
      this.previousParameter = userId;
    }
    
    return this.cache$;
  }

  private requestUser(userId: string) {
    return this.http.get<User>(API_ENDPOINT);
  }
}
```

And when you call `getUser()`, make sure you add `take(1)` or `first()` to your pipe so that you don't stay subscribed to a possibly stale observable:

```
this.userService.getUser('10').pipe(take(1))
                .subscribe(res => console.log('User:', res));
```